# Is there an RX extension to create an observable from another observable which only catches exceptions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Something functionally equivalent to this

```
//someObservable is an observable from another part of my application which produces Command objects
//can also have a ConnectionException

IObservable<Command> someObservable;

Subject<Command> sub = new Subject<Command>();

someObservable.Subscribe(c => { }, x =>
{
        sub.OnError(x);
});
```

This would allow me to have an observable just for exceptions so that I can handle them somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You could use Materialize/Dematerialize to filter everything out apart from exceptions. For example:

```
var subject = new Subject<int>();

var onlyExceptions = subject.Materialize().Where(n => n.Exception != null).Dematerialize();

subject.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 1: {0}", i),
                    ex => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 1 exception: {0}", ex.Message));

onlyExceptions.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 2: {0}", i),
                            ex => Console.WriteLine("Subscriber 2 exception: {0}", ex.Message));

subject.OnNext(123);
subject.OnError(new Exception("Test Exception"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This extension method will only ever return a single OnError, and if and only if the source sends OnError.

```
public static IObservable<T> ErrorsOnly<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return source.IgnoreElements().Concat(Observable.Never<T>());
}
```

Not sure how useful it is in practice though. IgnoreElements() might be enough for you if you aren't bothered about the OnCompleted();

Answer (score 0):

You could have one subscriber that only handles errors (and does nothing for regular items in the sequence), and use Catch() to eliminate errors everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that once an observable errors, it is finished. You can certainly subscribe, or use one of the Observable.Catch or Finally extension methods, but you'll only get the one error.